# Creating store in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]

createStore hook does not work in redux
what is the main problem ?

Comment: Please read [Are Point me in the right direction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/are-point-me-in-the-right-direction-questions-acceptable) questions acceptable?. Also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), to improve your experience on Stackoverflow next time. We accept much more specific questions...yours is not clear at all. Not sure whether you are getting an error or not and what do you mean by *createStore hook does not work in redux*?

Comment: `createStore` isn't a hook, it's a plain old function. Without knowing what the editor/IDE *thinks* the error is it's difficult to guess what problem you're having.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.